# Как правильно занимать и отпускать Mutex?

Tags: c#

Нужно, с одной стороны, обеспечить запуск единственного экземпляра приложения, с другой - в тестах надо имитировать запуск и выключение приложения.

Пишу соответствующие методы:

```
  public static class Client
  {
    private static Mutex mutex;

    public static void Start()
    {
      var isSingle = false;
      mutex = new Mutex(false, guid, out isSingle);
      if (!isSingle)
      {
        Log.Add("Программа уже запущена.");
        Environment.Exit(1);
      }
    }

    public static void Close()
    {
      if (mutex != null && !mutex.SafeWaitHandle.IsClosed)
      {
        Log.Add("Wait mutex...");
        mutex.WaitOne();
        mutex.ReleaseMutex();
        mutex.Close();
      }
    }
  }
```

Если создание и проверка в целом выглядят понятно, то вот с закрытием явные проблемы. По синтаксису хотелось вызвать просто `ReleaseMutex`, ему потребовался `WaitOne`, а потом оказалось, что `ReleaseMutex` не закрывает хендл и при следущем тесте старт уже невозможен, для чего пришлось добавлять ещё и `Close()`.

Вопрос - так и надо делать или есть варианты проще?

Comment: Судя по MSDN использование WinAPI проблему не решит: ReleaseMutex освобождает, CloseHandle закрывает хэндл.

Comment: WinForms-приложение?

Comment: @Stack просто либа на dotNet4.5

Comment: _"просто либа на dotNet4.5"_ -- ок. но в вопросе сказано "обеспечить запуск единственного экземпляра приложения". и если это WinForms-приложение, то есть решение.

Comment: @Stack в этом вся соль - пытаюсь написать приложение, которому легко будет нарисовать любой гуй. Но работа с базой из кучи приложений пока никак не обеспечивается, поэтому не больше одного процесса на базу. На текущий момент это CLI(консолька) и WPF.

Comment: @Stack для обеспечения запуска в единственном экземпляре достаточно кода в `Start`, кстати говоря, так что основная проблема в освобождении клиента для тестов.

Comment: _"основная проблема в освобождении клиента для тестов."_ -- сборки выгружаются только вместе с AppDomain. т.е. клиент должен быть запущен в отдельном AppDomain.

Comment: @Stack сборки сами по себе никому не мешают. Всмысле, кейсов типа а сейчас я подменю сборки и проверю запуск - пока по крайней мере нет.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35061/discussion-between-monk-and-stack).

Comment: На мой взгляд, самое главное при работе с объектами синхронизации тип `Mutex` - это правильная обрабока исключений. Поэтому я бы рекомендовал **всегда** использовать их в комбинации с `using` и `try-finally`. См [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/a/229567/315935). Код выглядит немного сложнее вначале, но в тех случаях, где применение объектов синхронизации действительно требуется, использование `using` и `try-finally` просто необходимо, чтобы избежать dedlock'ов.

Comment: @Oleg весь код приложения заворачивать в `using` и `try-catch-finally` мютекса? Звучит как то не очень.

Comment: не совсем так. см [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/a/94255/315935) или [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2329986/315935), например. Я хотел подчеркнуть, что код без `using` или `try-finally` почти всегда неправилен, хотя он и работает в большинстве случаев.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь использовать сразу два разных свойства мьютекса:

- Уникальность именнованного мьютекса в системе
- Возможность захватить его только одному клиенту одновременно

Первое свойство характерно не только для мьютексов, но для всех глобальных объектов синхронизации. Суть его в том, что в системе может существовать только один объект синхронизации с определенным именем.

Попытка создать такой же объект откроет уже существующий (созданный в другом процессе), но при этом явно вам на это укажет - возвратом параметра`createdNew == false`.

Мьютекс существует до тех пор, пока его хэндл не будет закрыт во всех процессах. Т.е. `createdNew` (ваш `isSingle`) будет выставлен в `false` в случае, если такой мьютекс уже где-то (в другом экземпляре приложения) существует.

Т.е. сам по себе механизм предотвращения повторного запуска опирается *исключительно* на свойство единственности существования именованного Mutex, а не на возможность эксклюзивно его захватить.

Методы `WaitOne`, `ReleaseMutex` и первый параметр конструктора - `initiallyOwned` используются для эксклюзивного захвата, и в вашем случае совершенно не нужны.

Минимальный код в вашем случае выглядит так:

```
public static class Client
{
    private static Mutex mutex;

    public static void Start()
    {
        var createdNew = false;
        mutex = new Mutex(false, "someid", out createdNew);
        if (!createdNew)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Программа уже запущена.");
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }
    }

    public static void Close()
    {
        if (mutex != null && !mutex.SafeWaitHandle.IsClosed)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Close handle");
            mutex.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Чтобы проверить, что сам по себе факт того, что вы используете именно `Mutex`, не влияет на результат, можете попробовать заменить его на что-то другое, например семафор с максимальным лимитом в 100:

```
new Semaphore(0, 100, "someid", out createdNew)
```

В отличии от мьютекса, его могут захватить до 100 раз. Но, как и в случае мьютекса, сама возможность захвата не используется - и он точно так же будет предотвращать запуск второго экземпляра - за счет уникальности имени.

Comment: я правильно понял, что `initiallyOwned` можно в любое состояние ставить, раз мне нужен один экземпляр приложения? Или в случае `true` могу получить исключение при попытке закрыть его из другого потока?

Comment: @Monk `initiallyOwned` срабатывает только при создании mutex - т.е. только с случае, если `createdNew` вернул true. Если мьютекс уже существовал - то попытки захвата не происходит. А для срабатывания `AbandonedMutexException` нужна именно попытка повторно захватить уже захваченный Mutex - т.е. для этого нужен именно вызов WaitOne. Пока вы WaitOne не вызываете, и вообще мьютексом именно как мьютексом не пользуетесь - значение `initiallyOwned` ни на что не вляет. Но лично я бы его оставил выставленным в false :)

Comment: @Monk кстати, вам действительно стоит поместить вызов Close в finally или в TestFinalize (который вызывается даже если тест упал). Дедлока вы не получите (вы же не используете мьютекс для синхронизации, и не ждете его - и лочится не на чем). Но если тест упадет и не вызовет Close - следующий тест просто выйдет из приложения.

Comment: В тестах `Client.Close()` как раз в финализаторе тестов, а вот в самом клиенте - вроде не критично, закрытие приложения мютекс освобождает. Спасибо за ответ, разобрался.